# Route is not defined Inertia.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In my controller, I have a method to redirect to a route:

```
return Redirect::route('/management');
```

This is my `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/management', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Management');
});
```

However, it throws an error saying `Route [management] not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect::route()` method expects a [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes), which you have not defined in your `routes/web.php` file.

In order to use a named route, you need to change your route to:

```
Route::get('/management', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Management');
})->name('management'); // added
```

After that, you can redirect to named routes in Inertia like so:

```
return Redirect::route('management');
```

Since we're using named routes, and not URLs, you should not include the leading `/` in your `route()` call.

Comment: Can we send data using return Redirect::route() method?

Comment: No, it's a redirection, so you can't send data to your response. Depending on your use case, you may be able to use a well defined route that includes parameters, but it's hard to say without knowing the full details of the data you need to send.